# The folder containing your music library cannot be found. Appears even after finding my library

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, music

When I attempt to open my Music app on my MacBook Pro (Early 2013), MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7, this message appears. [image]

When selecting Choose library, it takes me to my Music Folder where my iTunes folder is stored. Clicking on this folder and then selecting on iTunes Library.itl file as per the screenshots below simply takes me back to the original message.
[image]
[image]
I would prefer not to have to Create a new library from scratch or to use an older iTunes version (next oldest version was 2018, and I have used Music multiple times since then). The last time I used Music was in late 2020 or early 2021.

How I can get around this message and use my current iTunes library?